# Number the nth occurrence of a string

Tags: string, shell, replace

I want to find and replace some word that I find, but I want to replace it not with a fixed string, but with a variable one.

The file i have in input has some create table queries:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME
( .... ecc
)
```

I have to append before **each** CREATE a composed string like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DBC.TABLESV WHERE DATABASENAME = '<DB_NAME>' AND TABLENAME = '<TABLE_NAME>' AND TABLEKIND='T';
.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN .GOTO LABEL1 
DROP TABLE <DB_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>;
.LABEL LABEL1
```

**each LABEL** has to be numbered as the number of the occurrence.

so from 1 to the last CREATE statment

---

Comment: Thank you Inian for editing my question :)

Comment: This is a very different question than what was originally asked, which means the three existing answers (which were all decent answers to the original question) will no longer make sense.  It probably should have been a new question.

Comment: yeah i'm sorry about that :/

Answer (score 2):

Using perl

```
perl -pe 's/FOO/$&.$x++/ge' file
```

Will work for multiple FOO's per line.

```
FOO FOO FOO
.....
....
...
FOO yadda FOO
....
.....
......
FOO sf
.... sdfsdf
FOO dsf dfsfs
s dfsdf FOO s fds d FOO
.....
```

=>

```
FOO0 FOO1 FOO2
.....
....
...
FOO3 yadda FOO4
....
.....
......
FOO5 sf
.... sdfsdf
FOO6 dsf dfsfs
s dfsdf FOO7 s fds d FOO8
.....
```

Comment: To start counting at one instead of zero like the OP asked, switch to preincrement, as in `$&.++$x`.  It may also be worth explaining that removing the `g` will make this work for just the first instance on a line, if that's what's desired.

Comment: @dannysauer Removing the g would make no difference if there was only a single instance per line, and OP has not specified or even hinted that they only want to change the first occurence per line. Regardless, OP has changed their question completely now so the answer is probably not valid anymore anyway.

Comment: The point of the `/g` note was mostly to help other people looking for solutions and finding this answer (which was a good answer to the original question).  But, as you said, the question's so completely changed that this probably helps no one now. :/

Answer (score 1):

If `FOO` will only appear once on any line, you could use this awk script:

```
awk 'BEGIN { i=1; } { gsub(/FOO/, "FOO" i) && ++i; print }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` did the trick for me.

```
awk '/FOO/ { $0=$0 "" ++count }1' file
```

The logic is the pattern `FOO` is searched and from the entire file that is printed (done by `1`), we are matching a the pattern found with the `count` (here `$0` is the each instance of the pattern found, which is appended with the counter)

```
$ cat file
FOO
.....
....
...
FOO
....
.....
......
FOO
....
FOO
FOO
.....

$ awk '/FOO/ { $0=$0 "" ++count }1' file
FOO1
.....
....
...
FOO2
....
.....
......
FOO3
....
FOO4
FOO5
.....
```

Comment: what does it mean $0=$0 ?

Comment: @MartinMcFlyDeLuca: Interpret is as `$0=$0 "" ++count` which is basically, for the pattern found(`FOO` which is `$0`) append the running counter of the pattern.

Comment: where i have to put the string i want to replace?

**awk "/FOO/$NEWSTRING { $0=$0 "" ++count }1"**

Comment: @MartinMcFlyDeLuca: Please re-format the question with the exact output you are looking for instead of verbal explanations. It will be easy for  us to understand what you are looking for.